# Want to validate Angular Form, button submits no matter what error are present

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

So I've made a small Angular 5 app with a login form. I have put both "email" and "password" as a required field. If I select the field and lose focus, it will turn red indicating something's wrong. If I now submit my form, it will call my service & API no matter what, even if there's required errors.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="example-container">

  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" #loginForm="ngForm" *ngIf="this.showForm; else loadingTemplate">
    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="loginModel.email" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="loginModel.password" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-checkbox name="rememberMe" [(ngModel)]="loginModel.rememberMe">
        Remember Me
      </mat-checkbox>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <ng-template #loadingTemplate>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Please wait while your credentials are being checked...</p>
      <img src="../../assets/giphy.gif">
    </div>
  </ng-template>

</div>
```

And here's part of my .ts file:

```
loginForm: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit() {
this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
  loginModel: this.loginModel
});
}

onSubmit(e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.showForm = false;

      // TODO check if correct login
      this.loginService.postLoginData(this.loginModel)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/table');
          },
          error => {
            // alert('login failed');
            this.showForm = true;
            this.openSnackBar(`Login for email: ${this.loginModel.email} failed!`);
          });
    }

  }
```

My loginForm.valid always returns true. Can someone see what could be the problem?

Comment: How did you initialize `this.loginForm`?

Comment: Hi, I've added it to the code of my .ts file

Comment: Does it have a `@ViewChild` decorator ?

Answer (score 3):

First, instead of indenting your whole code, you can use the reverse condition like so :

```
if (this.loginForm.invalid) { return; }

// Your code
```

This seems like nothing, but once you understand that, you will gain so much time.

Next, the syntax for declaring your form is

```
@ViewChild('loginForm') loginForm: NgForm;
```

Right now, you're declaring a reactive form, and using the syntax of a template driven form.